# Laravel Eloquent Model adequate to Database Model

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a question regarding performance and code organization in my web application. I have a MySql DB tables: **user** (id, un, pass), **author** (id, signature...), **reader** (id, description), where *id* column in **user** correspondes the id's in those two tables. That DB model comes from ER model where **user** is a superclass of those two. In my app I want to get an **author** or **reader** along with the data from **user**, so my first question is: Can I make some kind of inheritance in Eloquent model to do this smoothely?

My current setup is that i created two VIEWs: authors (joins **user** and **author**) and readers (**joins** user and **reader**) and I plan to use them with WHERE clauses in Eloquent. Is this bad for performance? I know that MySql uses MERGE algorythm, so those queries will be translated in one SQL command, but if anyone has a proposal what is the best way to do this, please answer. Thanks!

Comment: You need to be more clear...
Are all your users author and reader ? Then, put all those fields (signature, description...) inside the user table. You don't need to make up those extra tables.

Comment: This kind of organizing DB tables and making Eloquent models should be more in my project, this is just one example. **Auhor** and **reader** are extedning **user**. In my app I can have just a **user**, or **reader** and **author** which inherits all from **user** and adds more fields. In the future I might have another **user** subclass, such as **administrator** with some additional fields. Having only one table is not a good modeling solution, I think.

Comment: If you really need to use separate tables, you should check the eloquent docs for [polymorphic relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)
I'll try to develop in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ER inside both models.

As example in your User.php model you should have a method called `author()`

```
class User extends Eloquent {

...

  // User has one Author
  public function author()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('Author');
  }

...

}
```

In your Author.php model you'll need to have

```
class User extends Eloquent {

...

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
  }

...

}
```

The same for Reader.php model.

You might take a look on the [docs page](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) ;)

Comment: Maybe I gave you a bad explanation, in my comment above I maybe explained better what I want to have. **User** does not to have a **author** or **reader**, that is **user** is not abstract. Can I have something like regular inheritance like in Java or C#?

Comment: To better understand what you need it would be better if you show me your migrations. I'm sorry, but I don't touch C# since ages and never seriously hooked into Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphic relations if a field can be linked to one table.

[Polymorphic relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations)

DB Schema :

```
user
    id - integer
    un - string
    pass - string
    role_id - integer  ; id of a row from either reader or author table
    role_type - string ; either reader or author

reader
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    description - text

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    signature - string
```

User.php

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function role() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
    ...
}
```

Reader.php

```
class Reader extends Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->morphMany('User', 'role');
    }
    ...
}
```

Author.php

```
class Author extends Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->morphMany('User', 'role');
    }
    ...
}
```

I am not sure this is the best way to go, though.

For example, you can never be sure that `$user->role->signature` will exist, you have to check if the user is a author first, or you might end up with unexpected errors.